# Can "tit for tat" strategy be defined in monadic second-order logic?

Tags: logic, game-theory, trees, higher-order-logic

Prisoner's dilema game can be represented as a *game tree*, which could be *infinite game* with corresponding *infinite game (binary) tree* in common case.

There is well-known *tit for tat* strategy, which can be optimal strategy for this game.

The question is: can this strategy be defined in monadic second-order logic for such infinite game tree? What will be the MSO-formula  in such case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with monadic second-order logic, but I would point out that _tit for tat_ is usually not optimal in the sense that it is not a SPE of the infinitely-repeated prisoner's dilemma. Having said that, in evolutionary game theory, it can in fact be optimal in some sense.  Does MSO relate to evolutionary GT?

Comment: Monadic second-order logic is a restriction of second-order logic in which only quantification over unary relations (is an element in a set, etc.). You are not at liberty to use binary relations like $=$, $\le$, etc.

Comment: @Axoren Could you please give more detailed **answer** with argumentation, why it isn't possible to define such strategy?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible to define such a strategy. I was commenting to @Shane about what monadic second-order logic was, in relation to full second-order logic. I've since been thinking about this problem and will see what I come up with, if I come up with anything at all.